# Elasticsearch not returning all documents for query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue with ES where I am applying a filter query but it's not returning all the documents that contain a query.

```
"query" => [
   "bool" => [
      "filter" => [
         "term" => [
            "group" => "green"
         ]
      ]
   ]
]
```

I know the query works as I'm getting some results but other documents that I also know have "green" in the group don't show.

Any ideas as to why some documents show and others don't? I've checked the spelling, checked if there are any weird spaces or characters in the group but it's exactly "green".

Index mapping is

```
'body' => [
   "mappings" => [
      "properties" => [
         "area" => [ "type" => "keyword" ],
         "category" => [ "type" => "keyword" ],
         "group" => [ "type" => "keyword" ]
       ]
   ],
   "settings" => [
      "analysis" => [
         "analyzer" => [
            "my_analyzer" => [
               "tokenizer" => "whitespace",
               "filter" => [ "stop" ]
            ]
         ]
...
```

Sample data is

```
{
   "_index": "test_index",
   "_type": "_doc",
   "_id": "0dbb19dd5b9ef01178ad",
   "_score": 0,
   "_source": {
      "area": "Shirts",
      "filepath": "",
      "jurisdiction": "Australia",
      "resource_type": "Document",
      "filesize": 1501430,
      "title": "Dashboard Update",
      "category": "Mens Shirts",
      "group": "green"
   }
}
```

Use case is that a user could search for a product by entering a query or they could click on a link to display all products belonging to a category, area or group.

Comment: can you share your index mapping and some sample index data?

Comment: Are you performing a search _immediately after_ indexing documents? If so, it may be possible that just indexed documents are not yet visible to search, because the index has not yet refreshed (controlled by explicitly refreshing the index upon indexing, or waiting for the `refresh_interval` to elapse)

Comment: No I'm not performing immediately but within a few min. Can I force index refresh?

Comment: @user1020496 can you share some sample index data also ?

Comment: @user1020496 by the index mapping, it seems as if you are using some analyzer also, can you please describe your use case also

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "group": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"pizza",
    "group":"red"
}
{
    "name":"multi grain bread",
    "group":"green"
}
{
    "name":"pizza",
    "group":"green"
}
```

**Saerch Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match" : { "group" : "green" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64025933",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.4700036,
        "_source": {
          "name": "multi grain bread",
          "group": "green"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64025933",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.4700036,
        "_source": {
          "name": "pizza",
          "group": "green"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**By using `bool filter query` also, the search result is there, just the difference is that scores are returned as 0.**

Comment: Thanks. I have tried a similar query but as mentioned, some documents dont get returned. When I do a search for the name I can see the product with all the correct field values but when I do a search with a filter/must match there are some that aren't returned.

Comment: @user1020496 that's weird :| , I tried it in my local and its working perfectly fine. Since you have already mentioned in the comments above that you are not performing search query immediately(so indexed documents are not yet visible to search, this possibility is not there). May be that documents are not indexed properly OR have you added `size` parameter in the search query, that brings out only few results ?

Comment: No as there are different numbers depending on the value I send and I can get ALL results to so no restriction on that. I'm pretty stumped here too as like I said, some are displaying but anything new I add is not showing.